# Upload form data fails with axios

Tags: javascript

I have a form with multiple fileds, which one is a file input. I use axios to upload the file under a separate attribute:

```
axios.post(ENDPOINT,{
  form: formData,
  image: image
}, getAuthorizationHeader())

function getAuthorizationHeader() {
  return {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': //...,
      'Content-Type': undefined
    }
  };
}
```

`formData` is created like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', values.title);
formData.append('description', values.description);
formData.append('amount', values.amount);
```

And the image is:

[image]

Under the network tab of the Chrome Dev tool, When I look at the request, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the file is empty? The `CONTENT-TYPE` is `application/json` which is not what I  expected. I expected browser to detect the `CONTENT-TYPE` as `multipart/form-data`

What is wrong here?

Comment: I could explain the rest, but not sure about the empty form. Is there any chance that formdata is undefined at the place you are making the axios call? Could you please post the full code?

Comment: I just watched a react tutorial with simple axios image upload. You could ignore the react stuff but take the axios code and adjust it to your needs: https://youtu.be/XeiOnkEI7XI

Comment: @ShivenSinha: apparently the form data doesn't show up in the dev tool. But why image is not into multi parts? why is the `CONTENT-TYPE` `application/json`?

Comment: @Luckyfella he is putting the file inside of a `FormData`, I tried that too. To instantiate a `FormData` and append image to it. But still the `Content-Type` remains `application/json`.

Comment: @Arian Now, in the file object, I see a preview property. I suppose you added that?

Comment: On the axios github page the is an upload example. He is using the PUT method instead of POST. Maybe you compare your code with the example: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html I have only my phone by hand so I can’t try get the code working

Comment: @Luckyfella A put instead of a post should not make a difference. If it does, it should be considered a bug of axios itself. This seems to be highly improbable, mainly because many people including me do use POST requests to send files. As for testing the code, that's exactly the case with me too :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `image` should be part of the `formData`:

```
formData.append('image', <stream-of-the-image>, 'test.png')
```

Secondly, `formData` should be the second parameter of `axios.post`:

```
axios.post(ENDPOINT, formData, getAuthorizationHeader())
```

Last but no least, you should merge `formData.getHeaders()`:

```
function getAuthorizationHeader() {
   return {
       headers: Object.assign({
           'Authorization': //...,
           }, formData.getHeaders())
    };
}
```

Sample code for your reference: https://github.com/tylerlong/ringcentral-js-concise/blob/master/test/fax.spec.js